# What is correct way formatting the below JSON?

Tags: c#, json, xml, soap

```
{
    "id": "bf96aa5d-daf7-4de6-8ab0-c5ceb57b43af",
    "created": "1582519813359",
    "result": {
        "status": "Succeed"
    },
    "amount": 6789,
    "provider_data": {
        "provider_name": "Magellan",
        "response_code": "00",
        "description": "Successful",
        "raw_response": "{\"raw_response\":\"
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\\\">
<soap:Body><ns2:doTransactionResponse xmlns:ns2=\\\"http://soap.api.controller.web.payjar.com/\\\"><return>
<merchantReference>e5638752-be88-423b-8db8-e181db4825651582519812683</merchantReference>
<MerReference>14976972006762</MerReference>
<resultCode>00</resultCode>
<resultMessage>Successful</resultMessage><successful>true</successful></return>
</ns2:doTransactionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>\"}",
        "transaction_id": "14976972006762"
    },
```

Above is the JSON which I am getting as a response. Till Raw_respose is JSON and I am able to read it as JSON. After that the inner raw_Reponse I am neither able to read as JSON nor XML nor SOAP. What exactly the format is and how can i read it in C#

I need to extract the  but not able to extract the inner raw_response in any format

Comment: eek, `raw_response` looks like its an escaped json object with nested soap. This is an example of a web developer needing to rethink their life choices

Comment: I know I am getting this from my merchant. its 3rd party. Still any way that I can get that value?

Comment: How are you receiving the response? Is its content type json? cause the snippet you have posted isn't valid json

Comment: Hi. Is this the actual response from the merchant, or did you, for clarification, made that soap response message multi-line? If you received this data as is, there is a problem. If not, I have your solution on my clipboard right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to the SOAP call by doing a couple of Deserialization calls.

1. Deserialize the json, main Json
2. Deserialzie the json, raw_response
3. Deserialize the xml, raw_response
4. Access the elements you need.

[dotnetfiddle working solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3upQSX)

**Classes you need for the SOAP XML**

```
[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{
    public EnvelopeBody Body { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://soap.api.controller.web.payjar.com/")]
    public doTransactionResponse doTransactionResponse { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://soap.api.controller.web.payjar.com/")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://soap.api.controller.web.payjar.com/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class doTransactionResponse
{

    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public @return @return { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[DesignerCategory("code")]
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class @return
{
    public string merchantReference { get; set; }
    public ulong MerReference { get; set; }
    public byte resultCode { get; set; }
    public string resultMessage { get; set; }
    public bool successful { get; set; }
}
```

**Code to use in the Main**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
            string json = @"{
    ""id"": ""bf96aa5d-daf7-4de6-8ab0-c5ceb57b43af"",
    ""created"": ""1582519813359"",
    ""result"": {
        ""status"": ""Succeed""
    },
    ""amount"": 6789,
    ""provider_data"": {
        ""provider_name"": ""Magellan"",
        ""response_code"": ""00"",
        ""description"": ""Successful"",
        ""raw_response"": ""{\""raw_response\"":\""
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\\\""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\\\"">
<soap:Body><ns2:doTransactionResponse xmlns:ns2=\\\""http://soap.api.controller.web.payjar.com/\\\""><return>
<merchantReference>e5638752-be88-423b-8db8-e181db4825651582519812683</merchantReference>
<MerReference>14976972006762</MerReference>
<resultCode>00</resultCode>
<resultMessage>Successful</resultMessage><successful>true</successful></return>
</ns2:doTransactionResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>\""}"",
        ""transaction_id"": ""14976972006762""
    }
}";
    // Convert the complete json first.
    var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var mainRawResponse = jobj["provider_data"]["raw_response"].ToString();

    // Convert the string version of the object
    var soapResponse= JObject.Parse(mainRawResponse)["raw_response"].ToString();
    Envelope data = null;

    // Conver the SOAP response.
    using (var reader = new StringReader(soapResponse))
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
        data = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

// data variable holds the data you need from SOAP xml.
Console.WriteLine(data.Body.doTransactionResponse);
Console.WriteLine(((@return)data.Body.doTransactionResponse.@return).merchantReference);

}
```